# Is ncurses available for windows?

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

Are there any ncurses libraries in C/C++ for Windows that emulate ncurses in native resizable Win32 windows (*not* in console mode)?

Comment: Do you know of [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/)? It's an implementation of the curses library for Windows. Is this not what you're looking for? What do you mean by console mode?

Comment: I use PDCurses, and though the doc claims you can resize the window,
I have not been able to do it.   You are limited by the settings of the console window.

Comment: EvilTeach you can resize the window with PDCurses, check out the testcurs.c in the demos of PDCurses, it demonstrates that effect.

Comment: [ncurses 5.8 (2011)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-5.8.html) added a port to MinGW.

Comment: Does any curses library work with the new Windows Terminal now?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's an ongoing effort for a PDCurses port:

http://www.mail-archive.com/pdcurses-l@lightlink.com/msg00129.html

http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The win32a project is in the right direction. I have spoken with the developer and there is a chance to see this implementation as part of the PDCurses at some point.

Comment: On Github: https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCursesMod

Answer (score 18):

Such a thing probably does not exist "as-is". It doesn't really exist on Linux or other UNIX-like operating systems either though.

ncurses is only a library that helps you manage interactions with the underlying terminal environment. But it doesn't provide a terminal emulator itself.

The thing that actually displays stuff on the screen (which in your requirement is listed as "native resizable win32 windows") is usually called a Terminal Emulator. If you don't like the one that comes with Windows (you aren't alone; no person on Earth does) there are a few alternatives. There is [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), which in my experience works sometimes and appears to just wrap an underlying Windows terminal emulator (I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing, since there is a menu option to actually get access to that underlying terminal emulator, and sure enough an old crusty Windows/DOS box appears which mirrors everything in the Console window).

**A better option**

Another option, which may be more appealing is [puttycyg](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/). It hooks in to Putty (which, coming from a Linux background, is pretty close to what I'm used to, and free) but actually accesses an underlying cygwin instead of the Windows command interpreter (`CMD.EXE`). So you get all the benefits of Putty's awesome terminal emulator, as well as nice `ncurses` (and many other) libraries provided by cygwin. Add a couple command line arguments to the Shortcut that launches Putty (or the Batch file) and your app can be automatically launched without going through Putty's UI.

Comment: Unfortunately puttycyg was discontinued. Personally, I recommend [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/) combined with [Cygwin Ports](https://sourceware.org/cygwinports/), using the quite comfortable RoxTerm terminal emulator.