# Console overwriting like top

Tags: c++, c, linux

Ok so I was just wondering how console applications like `top(1)` for linux overwrite multiple lines. I want to know how to do it for C++ or C. I know how to overwrite 1 line by just putting a \r but I wanted to know how to do so for multiple lines, again like in top or if its even possible.

Comment: It's platform-dependent. Which platform are you on?

Comment: Linux is probably where I'm goign to want to be doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use terminal escape sequences to move the cursor around the screen.  A few even use direct framebuffer access, to treat the screen as an array of characters which can be directly indexed.

The `curses` (or `ncurses`) library is a good abstraction layer.

Comment: Just a note, but curses doesn't really exist on Windows: [Is ncurses available for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/138153/16487)

Comment: @C.Ross: That question asks about replacement terminal emulators that support the curses API.  `curses` is certainly available for console mode applications.

Comment: pdcurses actually is very usable, I haven't had any problems with porting my ncurses applications using basic ASCII characters to pdcurses on Windows. if you're using ncursesw, the UTF-8 compatible incarnation of ncurses, you'll probably run into a lot more trouble.

Comment: @Daniel: cygwin-installed ncurses apps such as vim work just fine, I don't see why a self-developed app should have any more problems.

Answer (score 2):

This may not directly address the question, but this sort of thing is dependent on the terminal and is commonly done with a curses implementation ([ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) is the most widely used).