# Library for Dialogs and Widgets in Win32 Console Application ( in C )

Tags: c, linux, console, ncurses

I've seen a lot of console apps (that run on windows) having some dialog boxes and widgets inside them. Say for example:

[image]

A there are a lot more. Now my question: Is there any library (in C) for creating dialogs and widgets in a Win32 Console App?

UPDATE: Seen pdcurses, but it lacks libraries from the real ncurses library like menu.h and form.h. So ss there any other that is easy to use?
Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: GUIs have been mainstream for the past 15 years.  Little point in trying to find a library like this when there are plenty of good ones that give you a decent user interface.

Comment: @HansPassant: What nonsense. There are _many_ contexts in which that is not an option. An engineering configuration menu over a serial link, for example.

Comment: I also want to know the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use ncurses, please check the following question from stackoverflow.com:
[Is ncurses available for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows)

there is also [PDCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/) that support Win32

you can also use the old library [Turbo vision](http://tvision.sourceforge.net/), I have never tested it on win32.

Answer (score 1):

The cygwin suite should contain a complete port of ncurses.

Comment: Would you please stop writing "Bye" on a new line at the end of all your posts?

Answer (score 0):

if you ou can get hold of an old borland C/C++ (v3.1 if I remember correctly or 6.0, I guess the former version). It has a framework to get just the same that you showed in your picture.