# How to include and use turbo vision library in Turbo C++ 3

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I would like to ask this question to those people who have an experience in coding using Turbo C++ 3.0.

I'm trying to make a text user interface console application with it and I see that Turbo C++ 3 has an option to link turbo vision in your program.

Using this: Options -> Linker -> Libraries -> Check Turbo Vision.

Know my question is that how could I start using it in my program?
I tried to include  but to no avail, or to not include the header also.

Note: If you know of other way to develop C++/C console apps with text user interface, then please feel free to answer to.

Thanks!

Edit: Please do not comment to not to use Turbo C++ because it's old. I'm just trying to create a console app with text user interface for our project. Thanks :)

Comment: Do not use Turbo C++.  It is ancient.  Use a modern C++ compiler, like the latest version of Visual C++ or gcc.

Comment: I would like to... But I really need to develop console apps with text user interface similar to Turbo C++'s interface itself and that's why I'm needing it. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: You don't need Turbo C++. What can you do in that that can't be done in a modern environment?

Comment: If you are considering alternatives to Turbo Vision, there's [**ncurses**](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), a GNU library. I'd suppose its advantage is that it's cross-platform. Getting it to work with the Turbo C++ 3 compiler and linker *could* be a challenge, though.

Comment: Its cross platform, so I can use it on windows environment right? Is there any resources out there on how to use it using modern IDEs? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Turbo Vision is out dated and no more maintained. However, if have you
>   stronger reasons to use a completely 'The DOOM' game era TUI tool kit,
>   they go ahead else i would suggest using [ncurses](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/) it is a portable
>   TUI toolkit, [image]

**As note, Turbo Vision library has potentially unsafe pointers. It is not a safe 
library to use in this era**, and it is a DOS 'only' thing, those there are ports to
POSIX based environment , i still doubt its safety.

Comment: Really nice :) ... It's cross platform so its also available for Windows environment right? Is there any resources out there on how to use Ncurses on windows with Code::Blocks IDE or Dev C++ IDE? Thanks!

Comment: Kindly see [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows) if you liked the answer kindly accept and vote up ;-)

Comment: it's still maintained on github.