# Move text cursor to particular screen coordinate?

Tags: c++, c, windows, console

How can I set the cursor at the desired location on the console in C or C++?

I remember a function called `gotoxy(x,y)`, but I think its deprecated. Is there any alternative?

Comment: That is not part of standard C or C++. You'll have to use an API. What kind of cursor are you referring to? Mouse? Keyboard cursor in terminal?

Comment: Once you want something more than a linear text output, get away from the console entirely.  There are too many idiosyncracies to worry about, on the developer's side and on the user's side.  Get a library that supports 2D graphics([SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)), and output text using graphical text output functions.

Comment: If you're on Unix, the `curses` or `ncurses` library provides the facilities you're after.

Comment: I am on windows and I am writing a console application. I don't know much about the 2D graphics library..

Comment: That's why I provided links.  And I'm telling you specifically to get away from the console.  It's not made for this.  It's made for putting out characters, one after another, in a linear fashion.

Comment: Perhaps you could try some of [these suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows)

Comment: PDCurses: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDCurses . You could also look at the code for i.e. Midnight Commander (which is Unix/Win). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander , Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface .

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I disagree.  The Windows console is perfectly well suited to many simple 2D text tasks, and it's a whole lot simpler than mucking about with a general-purpose multimedia library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There are a bunch of other functions in the same part of the MSDN library.  Some of them may be useful too.

Answer (score 13):

Neither C nor C++ have any notion of a screen or console; they only see streams of bytes, which have no inherent display characteristics.  There are a number of third-party APIs like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) to help you do that.

If you want a quick-n-dirty solution *and* the terminal you're working with understands [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), then you can do things like

```
printf("\033[%d;%dH", row, col);
```

to move the cursor to a specific row and column (where the top left corner is {1,1}).  You'd be better off using ncurses, though (or the equivalent for your platform).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to set the cursor to specific coordinates on the screen, and then simply use cout<< or printf statement to print anything on the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void set_cursor(int,int);

int main()
{
     int x=0 , y=0;
     set_cursor(x,y);
     cout<<"Mohammad Usman Sajid";

     return 0;
}

void set_cursor(int x = 0 , int y = 0)
{
    HANDLE handle;
    COORD coordinates;
    handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    coordinates.X = x;
    coordinates.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition ( handle , coordinates );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are talking about [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library, the function you are after is `move (row, column)`.

Answer (score 2):

I use a really simple method. You don't overly need to know what a HANDLE is unless you're really diving into console applications, a COORD object is in the windows.h standard library and has two member data intergers X and Y. 0,0 is the top left corner and Y increases to go down the screen. You can use this command and just continue to use std::cout<< to print whatever you need.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(void){
//initialize objects for cursor manipulation
HANDLE hStdout;
COORD destCoord;
hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

//position cursor at start of window
destCoord.X = 0;
destCoord.Y = 0;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout, destCoord);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was on stackoverflow...

```
`#include <stdio.h>

// ESC-H, ESC-J (I remember using this sequence on VTs)
#define clear() printf("\033[H\033[J")

//ESC-BRACK-column;row (same here, used on terminals on an early intranet)
#define gotoxy(x,y) printf("\033[%d;%dH", (y), (x))

int main(void)
{
    clear();
    gotoxy(23, 12);
    printf("x");
    gotoxy(1, 24);
    return 0;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows: #include<windows.h>

> #define cursor(x, y) SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), (COORD){x, y})

For Linux:

> #define cursor(x,y) printf("\033[%d;%dH", x, y)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out this to set the cursor.

```
#include <iostream>

void setPos(std::ostream& _os, const std::streamsize& _x, const std::streamsize& _y)
{
    char tmp = _os.fill();

    if(_y>0) {
            _os.fill('\n');
            _os.width(_y);
            _os << '\n';
    }
    if(_x>0) {
            _os.fill(' ');
            _os.width(_x);
            _os << ' ';
    }
    _os.flush();
    _os.fill(tmp);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setPos(std::cout, 5, 5);
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To do more you'll need assumptions on the resolution or a lib like [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Comment: Unlike gotoxy, your function can only move the cursor forward. Also, the position is relative to the current cursor-position in your solution - if the cursor is at (x,y), then a call to setPos(a,b) moves to ((y==0?x:0)+a,y+b) - so the new x-coordinate depends on the parameter you pass for y.

Comment: Exactly. It is _shifting_ the output by a desired offset. In fact it does this by producing output. If I recall correctly I used something like this for table-like output formatting.

Comment: If you print `\r` and then move forward, you can advance to an arbitrary column, right? You would only be able to control the Y coordinate if you knew the width of the terminal, since the output would naturally wrap at intervals of that. If it works at all, I would start with a `\r` or `\n` to make sure you're starting at (0,0), and make sure nothing prints at the same time.