# How do i show the other "cout" things before inputing a cin?

Tags: c++

im supposed to do this

```
Main Menu 
A – Arithmetic Series    
B – Geometric Series     
C – Harmonic Mean     
D – Geometric mean    
E - Taylor Polynomial of Degree n 
F – Largest Prime Number    
Enter your choice:
```

inside a box

my code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfloat>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string menu;

    cout<<"_._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._\n";
    cout<<"|            Main Menu              |\n";
    cout<<"|                                   |\n";
    cout<<"|A - Arithmetic Series              |\n";
    cout<<"|B - Geometric Series               |\n";
    cout<<"|C - Harmonic Mean                  |\n";
    cout<<"|D - Geometric Mean                 |\n";
    cout<<"|E - Taylor Polynomial of Degree n  |\n";
    cout<<"|F - Largest Prime Number           |\n";
    cout<<"|Enter your choice:\n";
    cin>> menu;
    cout<<"_._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._\n";


}
```

can someone help me out? i need to input a letter inside the box, but the box wont completely form because of the cin thingy

Comment: oh sorry, should i have had typed it instead?

Comment: @DericJose just paste it in the question and format it.

Comment: oh okay thanks, in a sec

Comment: Yes, all questions on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information in the question itself ***as plain text***. Suspicious links to dodgy external web sites can stop working at any time rendering the question meaningless.

Comment: How you do this depends entirely on the terminal emulator you are running your program in. Most people us a library like `ncurses` for this kind of thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move text cursor to particular screen coordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401724/move-text-cursor-to-particular-screen-coordinate)

Answer (score 2):

When it reaches `cin`, the program stops and asks you for input. So just move `cin` after the output statements.

For exmaple, you can move the `cin` line to the bottom. Then you can see the whole box before the program asks you to input a value.

Is this what you want? 
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string menu;

    cout << "|_._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._|\n";
    cout << "|            Main Menu              |\n";
    cout << "|                                   |\n";
    cout << "|A - Arithmetic Series              |\n";
    cout << "|B - Geometric Series               |\n";
    cout << "|C - Harmonic Mean                  |\n";
    cout << "|D - Geometric Mean                 |\n";
    cout << "|E - Taylor Polynomial of Degree n  |\n";
    cout << "|F - Largest Prime Number           |\n";
    cout << "|_._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._|\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice:\n";
    cin >> menu;
}
```

Btw, you need to use `#include <string>` if you use `string`.

---

This [image] ?

Comment: Thanks! but now I can only input the value outside the box, is there a way i can input the value inside it? without breaking the box?

Comment: @DericJose  I don't understand. If you want to input inside the box, then the box won't complete before you input.

Comment: my prof wanted to have the "Enter your choice: (and the answer) " thing inside the box, is that even possible?
edit: ok i just read your reply thanks!!

Comment: @DericJose Then you should enter something as a input in your original program. See my answer after edited.

Comment: thank you sir! Ill use the 1st one that you showed since it looks way better

Comment: Putting the prompt inside the box is *possible*, but not *easy* or *portable*. It would require you to output the entire box including the prompt, then MOVE THE INPUT CARET back to where you want after the prompt. There is no standard API in C++ to do that, though, but there are platform-specific terminal APIs that can. That is usually outside the scope of typical school courses, though. If your teacher wants this, he should have taught you how to do it.