# how to install curses library in c++?

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

i cannot find anything in the internet that gives tutorial on how to install curses.h library on Code Lite. It bugs me it always gives the error:

```
C:/Program Files/CodeLite/ADF C++ Training/Testing/main.cpp:1:20: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
#include <curses.h>
^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Testing.mk:93: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o' failed
```

Comment: The question makes no sense. The curses library is not installed "in c++". The curses library gets installed in some operating system. This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236908/add-curses-library-to-visual-studio-c

Comment: i mean, i want to add curses library to CodeLite

Comment: I disagree on the duplicate of that one, the problem seems to be different here. CodeLite documentation should help you with installing a library. Usually you just need to put the files in a folder your compiler sees and link the library files for the linker to see them.