# How To add Ncurses to my Project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ncurses

I'm searching for a detailed step by step guide to add Ncurses to my project in Visual Studio 2017. I downloaded the source code, but I have no idea how to add it to my project. I know this question will be dumb for you, but I'm a beginner concerning C++ and do not find a tutorial online to add Ncurses to my project. I looked through the online documentation etc. but didn't find any helpful hint. I'm writing a console application.

I downloaded the code from: https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/#download_ncurses

Thank you for your help.

---

**EDIT:**

I know there is this solution:

```
#include <windows.h> 
void gotoxy( short x, short y ) 
{ 
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) ; 
    COORD position = { x, y } ; 

    SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdout, position ) ; 
}
```

but I guess that's Windows specific. So what could I do instead which works for both: Unix/Windows.

Comment: From where did you download the source code? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Following two links might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236908/add-curses-library-to-visual-studio-c and https://jdonaldmccarthy.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/how-to-set-up-pdcurses-in-visual-studio-2013-c/

Comment: @Jabberwocky I already saw the first post, this doesn't help, to the second: the file I need to download (provided in the tutorial) is not found. I do not find the curses.h file in the folder I downloaded. I only find curses.p.h and curses.h.in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NCurses is UNIX library, i.e. available for POSIX UNIX-es like Linux, FreeBSD, MacOS X etc. There is [PDCurses](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses) which support Windows, and you can replace ncurses with PDCurses in your program and use it with POSIX and another systems like DOS, Windows etc.

Please follow the [PDCurses build manual](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/wincon/README.md). And check [demos code](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/tree/master/demos)