# Running two functions at the same time. (Real Time)

Tags: c++

I was not able to do this.
What I want is this,
While the code is working in real time, the user will be able to take any action he wants.

```
  (...)

int main (){

    time = 60; 
    string input;

    cout << "Time: " << time << endl << endl; // Time needs to decrease every second. 
    // (time--,sleep(1000))
    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> Input; // The user can take the action he wants at this time.

  (...)
}
```

I'm waiting for your help, thank you.

Comment: not completely clear what you want that code to do. What two functions should run at the same time? What do you mean with "take any action" ?

Comment: In other words, while time is running out, the user can use the "cin" function, but he should see the time decreasing on the screen.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate to this [Running a timer while other commands are being executed c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877961), but it should be noted that the suggested solution does not work well.

Comment: As [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053175/is-it-possible-to-set-timeout-for-stdcin) tells, you cannot use `std::cin` for your job. You may want to search other functions that take input asynchroniously.

Comment: [is this question related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736536/c-input-and-output-to-the-console-window-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Thanks [is this question related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736536/c-input-and-output-to-the-console-window-at-the-same-time) this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::thread` to have a second thread of execution. That thread can sleep 60 times for `std::chrono::seconds{1}` each tick. That second thread *can* write to `std::cout`. But this can mix with the input the user is typing! This can be quite confusing. Also, after those 60 seconds the user still needs to enter something.

Formally: It's not Undefined Behavior. It won't crash.