# In c, how do I continuously print text out until the user enters a specific character?

Tags: c

I want to print out text (from a file previously opened) until I press the key `q`. All of the methods I have tried pause my text being printed out. Is there a way to print the text while looking for a key press in C?

ex:

```
//after turning off canonical mode and echoing

char* output = "press q to stop this";

char ch;

while(ch = getchar()!= 'q')
{
    printf("%s\n",output);
}
```

It only prints the prompt after you enter a char. I want it to continue to print the prompt continuously.

Solved my problem with this webpage that I found: http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], and post a [mcve].

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: Please show us what you have done. :)

Comment: added an example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197977/how-can-i-prevent-scanf-to-wait-forever-for-an-input-character

Comment: I found this webpage and I was able to solve my problem with it. [link](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/

I understand my question was too broad but this is how I solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a child process.

- parent prints elem from file
- child waiting user input
- to stop execution you can use kill(getppid(), SIGTERM) to kill parent and exit(0) to kill child

Comment: Might be worth a mention of threads too

Comment: @tijko In my opinion, in this case, is easier with a child process.

Comment: because of the way I'm getting the text I want to print out I don't think I can easily use a child process. Is there a way to do this outside of a child process?

Comment: @joeGV you can use select to stdin

Answer (score 0):

Based on `jave.web`'s response in [Wait for input for a certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192230/wait-for-input-for-a-certain-time)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<windows.h>


char waitForCharInput( int seconds ){
    char c = '_'; //default return
    while( seconds != 0 ) {
        if( _kbhit() ) { //if there is a key in keyboard buffer
            c = _getch(); //get the char
            break; //we got char! No need to wait anymore...
        }

        Sleep(1000); //one second sleep
        --seconds; //countdown a second
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("_filename_","r");
    char buffer[255];
    while(fgets(buffer, 255, (FILE*) fp))
    {
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        char response = waitForCharInput(1);
        if(response == 'q')
            break;
    }
}
```