# Colorize special words in a string

Tags: c++, linux, colors

I have a linked list of nodes which described below:

```
class ColorGr
{
    string word;
    string color;
    ColorGr *next;
}
```

I have a string and I want to search for "word"s in it and colorize them with "color".

I tried ncurses to do that but the problem is with using windows. I don't want the screen being refreshed.

I want to print the string in output just like a `cout` function. My code is in c++ language and I work with gcc in linux. 
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Cout itself wont be able to help you, it depends on where you are printing to. You should try to use ncurses (lookup cygwin) or try to find something that works with windows cmd

Comment: @KarthikT That's only partially true. He can add formatting state to `std::cout` using its `iword` and `pword` members, and define custom manipulators. Or he can interpose a custom `std::streambuf` subclass to colorize the words as they're going to the screen. But the DOS text buffer support alone is probably enough for this one question.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you can use console APIs, and manipulate colors:

```
  DWORD dummy = 0;
  const WORD color = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE; // gray
  HANDLE console = ::GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute (console, color);
  WriteConsoleA (console, msg.data (), msg.length (), &dummy, NULL);
```

[more colors here (link)](http://www.cprogramming.com/snippets/source-code/color-header-for-windows-that-integrates-with-cout)

Or another way, for Linux, you can use [ANSI color codes](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html) (not all terminals support, most (except for windows) should.)

e.g.

```
  fprintf (stdout, "\e[0;36m" "cyan colored text" "\e[0m");
```

Comment: thanks but is it possible to pass parameters to    printf    function ? for example    string s="36m"    and pass it the function ?

Comment: Ofcourse, it is certainly possible : `fprintf (stdout, "%s" "cyan colored text" "\e[0m", "\e[0;36m");`

Answer (score 0):

As far as the windows issue is concerned, I don't know if you haved looked at PDACurses, so here is a SO link just in case [Ncurses workaround for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows).

Comment: I code in linux and I think there's a misunderstanding here . I meant window concept in ncurses not Windows operating system in my question anyway I appreciate your answer.