# Making a countdown timer in C++

Tags: c++, windows, countdown

I have a console application that is intended to **only run on windows**. It is written in **C++**. Is there any way to wait **60 seconds** (and **show remaining time** on screen) and then continue code flow?

I've tried different solutions from the internet, but none of them worked. Either they don't work, or they don't display the time correctly.

Comment: A for loop that sleeps 1 second 60 times?

Comment: What *have* you tried? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Exactly. But I need to display the remaining time on screen, and I can't figure out how to do that. I can't figure out a way to clear only specific parts of the screen.

Comment: How about using the carriage-return to overwrite what you previously wrote? Like e.g. `std::cout << "\rTime remaining: " << std::setw(5) << counter << std::flush;`

Comment: @H4ZE So your question is actually "How to clear only part of the console?", right? If you search for that, you'll land at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063076/clearing-only-part-of-the-console-output) answer. That's assuming you mean the console with "the screen", that part is not clear.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 's comment actually worked, but I feel the countdown is faster than 60 seconds. Like the actual seconds are faster. Here's my code:     `int counter = 60;
    while (counter >= 1)
    {
        cout << "\rTime remaining: " << setw(5) << counter << flush;
        _sleep(1000);
        counter--;
    }`

Comment: use `SetWaitableTimer` with `CompletionRoutine` and period==1 sec and `SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);`- print remaing time from callback

Comment: There is no need to use Windows-specific code if you have access to a C++11 compiler. You can replace the `sleep()` function with `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`. Have a look at [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Please note that this is Windows specific code
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int counter = 60; //amount of seconds
    Sleep(1000);
    while (counter >= 1)
    {
        cout << "\rTime remaining: " << counter << flush;
        Sleep(1000);
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make it cross-platform if you use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: Unsurprisingly, you need to `#include <thread>`. And it's generally a good practice to avoid platform-specific code when you can. Right now it doesn't need to run on other OSes, but that might change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sleep() system call to sleep for 60 seconds.

You can follow this link for how to set 60 seconds timer using system call [Timer in C++ using system calls](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timer-c-using-system-calls/).

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I want a **countdown**, not a timer.

Answer (score 0):

possible use [*Waitable Timer Objects*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/waitable-timer-objects) with perion set to 1 second for this task. possible implementation

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerAPCProc(
                           __in_opt  LPVOID /*lpArgToCompletionRoutine*/,
                           __in      DWORD /*dwTimerLowValue*/,
                           __in      DWORD /*dwTimerHighValue*/
                           )
{
}

void CountDown(ULONG Seconds, COORD dwCursorPosition)
{
    if (HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(0, 0, 0))
    {
        static LARGE_INTEGER DueTime = { (ULONG)-1, -1};//just now
        ULONGLONG _t = GetTickCount64() + Seconds*1000, t;
        if (SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &DueTime, 1000, TimerAPCProc, 0, FALSE))
        {
            HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            do 
            {
                SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);
                t = GetTickCount64();
                if (t >= _t)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsoleOutput, dwCursorPosition))
                {
                    WCHAR sz[8];
                    WriteConsoleW(hConsoleOutput, 
                        sz, swprintf(sz, L"%02u..", (ULONG)((_t - t)/1000)), 0, 0);
                }
            } while (TRUE);
        }
        CloseHandle(hTimer);
    }
}
    COORD dwCursorPosition = { };
    CountDown(60, dwCursorPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be of some help, it's not entirely clear what the question is but this is a countdown timer from 10 seconds, you can change the seconds and add minutes as well as hours.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
  #endif
 int main()
 {
   for (int sec = 10; sec < 11; sec--)
 {
      cout << setw(2) << sec;
      cout.flush();

      sleep(1);
      cout << '\r';
      if (sec == 0)
      {
      cout << "boom" << endl;
      }
      if (sec <1)
      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In c++ you can use countdown. please go through with the following logic which will allow you to show remaining time on the screen.

```
for(int min=m;min>0;min--)  //here m is the total minits as per ur requirements
{
for(int sec=59;sec>=;sec--)
{
sleep(1);                   // here you can assign any value in sleep according to your requirements.
cout<<"\r"<<min<<"\t"<<sec;
}
}
```

if you need more help on this then please follow the [link here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216933/a-countdown-timer-in-c)

Hope it will work, please let me know that it is working in your case or not? or if you need any help.

Thanks!