# Terminal app which takes up the whole terminal

Tags: c, terminal, command-line-interface, xterm

I have been trying to figure out how to make an app similar to emacs in that when you run it, it runs in the terminal but it takes up the whole terminal and acts almost like a window.  I can't find anything online about this, can anyone give me pointers of where to get started to figure this out?

Comment: Sometimes simple single widgets like dialog provide (http://www.unixcl.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html) might be enough, depends on your scenario. Otherwise, (n)curses is the kind-of-standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *nix, there is [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) explains it to you: It is a library to write "GUI-like" applications in text format.

Also: [Ncurses for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows)