# Is there a better way to analyze the key which was pressed without printing on the screen in C (eg. Arrow keys and Return)?

Tags: c, keystroke

Code snippet [(Full code here.)](https://raw.github.com/kevin-dong-nai-jia/CUI-Text-Editor-Dev/master/main.c) :

```
int Process (void)
{
  for (;;)
  {
    unsigned char Char_Fore = getch();
    if (Char_Fore == 0xE0)
    {
      unsigned char Char_Back = getch();
      switch (Char_Back)
      {
        case 0x48:
          Up();
          break;
        case 0x50:
          Down();
          break;
      }
    }
    else if (Char_Fore == 0x0D)
      Enter();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code can run properly on some machine, but some can't because of the `getch()` function.

[`getch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//Library/ms235446.aspx) or [`_getch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/078sfkak.aspx) is a function declared in [`conio.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) , and the return value would vary if your keyboard is not IBM set 2, or the different compiler were chosen (not Mingw-gcc).

Is there a better way to analyze the key which was pressed in C without printing on the screen and without using a deprecated function like [`getch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//Library/ms235446.aspx) or [`_getch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/078sfkak.aspx) **in console**?

Comment: You're already using the winAPI, you don't need conio (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) or [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), sounds like kind of thing you want to be using.

[PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) seems to be the Windows option - [Is ncurses available for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows)

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't really an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I recall using a header called termios.h, and using it I could turn off echoing of characters, now this was on a UNIX system, but I'd imagine there's a Windows equivalent.

Here's the pressanykey code with windows.h, perhaps you could adjust it to your needs?
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7312/#msg33734

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems that it is OS-specific. I think I'll give PDCurses a try.

Comment: Now at 60+, you should have "comment everywhere" "Leave comments on other people's posts"

Comment: Hurray for comments! Good luck!:)