# Update screen in C console

Tags: c, console, console-application

Im tring to make a snake game in consoles whit C. My question is how can i update the screen better than doing `system("cls");` every time in the game loop, because that causes screen flicker and i dont like it.

Comment: whatever you try, its gonna be hard to get it super portable. i suggest using something like ncurses to abstract this stuff away

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to do can be achieved by using termcaps/ncurses.

Last time I had to do something like that I used this website. It may help you as well :

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

The thing is that it won't be portable to windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yami beat me.

NCURSES is what you want.

If you need something on Windows you could try the suggestion supplied here:
[Is ncurses available for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows)

EDIT: I would have just commented, but I do not have the reputation.