# How to underline input string in c language

Tags: c, string, char

How to underline input string in c language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
printf("Enter String\n");
    gets(usr);
     puts(usr);
}
```

Comment: Oh don't use `gets()` it's deprecated. Also, where is the declaration of `usr`? and `main()` needs a return type it's `int`.

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows doesn't have underlined console output.

Comment: If you want a C answer, don't tag C++.

Comment: Since terminal capabilities vary, there is no portable way to do this. You might consider a library like ncurses, but [I don't think that will work for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/138153/10077).

Comment: What kind of underlining do you need? Would printing the text followed by a line of hyphens meet your requirements? BTW, `main()` should be `int main(void)` -- and you have't declared `usr`.

Comment: @iharob: Omitting the return type of a function is permitted under C89/C90 rules; it default to `int`. C99 removed the "implicit `int`" rule. You still *should* declare it explicitly as `int main(void)`, but this is why you can often get away with just `main()` for some compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about windows on linux this is pretty simple

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char text[100];
    if (fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        size_t length;

        length = strlen(text);
        if (text[length - 1] == '\n')
            text[length - 1] = '\0';
        printf("the following text \033[4m");
        printf("%s", text);
        printf("\033[24m, was underlined\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically wrapping the text around `"\e[4m"` and `"\e[24m"` does it, the former enables underlined text, and the latter disables it. You can search google for `BASH escape sequences` for colors and other stuff.

You can also create a function that underlines a certain string, although that's not so easy in c as it is in Java.

Comment: The escape sequences are implemented by the terminal emulator (`xterm` or whatever you're using); they're not specific to bash. There's a list of xterm control sequences at http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Comment: The `\e` escape is non-standard; gcc supports it, but will warn about it with `-pedantic`. Use `\x1b` (which assumes an ASCII-like character set, but you're assuming that already).