# ANSI escape sequences displaying incorrectly when used as an alternative for gotoxy()

Tags: c, ansi-escape

conio.h and gotoxy does not work with my compiler for C. I tried searching for solutions on the web and found the following:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", y, x);
}
```

However, it does not position the cursor as intended. It only displays

```
←[1;10H
```

when I try to set x and y to 10 and 1 respectively. I have found other alternatives like using SetConsolePosition but I would still like to know if using ANSI escape sequences would work.

I am currently using the CodeBlocks IDE.

Comment: I'd imagine that would be dependant on the terminal?

Comment: Whether or not your terminal supports ANSI escapes is totally a function of what terminal you are using. Some do, some don't. `\033[<L>;<C>H` can also be written as `\033[<L>;<C>f` (with `'f'` instead of `'H'`). You may want to try if that is implemented. Otherwise try a few other escapes. If none work, then your terminal likely doesn't support ANSI escapes. (VT 100 terminal emulation should support the ANSI escapes)  `tput` is another way to manipulate the terminal. Or, as you have found, `SetConsolePosition` is what works with that terminal.

Comment: why not use curses? or ncurses

Comment: @pm100 how would I use curses or ncurses ?

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html if windows see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows

Comment: Using `SetConsoleCursorPosition` in Windows is a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: The Windows Terminal needs a to be initialized with SetConsoleMode to use these sequences